# do we need azure portal account to use azure devops?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I want to use azure devops for my website ex."www.abc.com". The domain name is from the third party web hosting company. I want to perform continuous deployment for this site. is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

No, you dont need to link Azure Devops to Azure Subscription to use it. How to do that (deploy to your website using Azure Devops) is a really broad question, you need to be more concrete with what have you tried and what doesnt work. I suggest starting a new question for that.

Here's how you would create an Azure Devops organization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=azure-devops
Here's how you would create an Azure Devops project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I've already created devops organization & project. I've also imported my project from my machine. I just wanted to know how to link my website with azure devops so that I can deploy it in octopus or Jenkins.

Comment: this question doesnt make any sense, why link it with azure devops if you plan on using jenkins or octopus?

Comment: I will use azure devops for project build only and for deploment, I will use Jenkins or octopus.

Comment: oh, ic. in that case you need to build and push artifacts to some location (nuget feed, docker registry or something like that and then use jenkins\octopus to pull those and deploy to the target server

Comment: Can you please share some link w.r.t this.

Comment: "How to do that (deploy to your website using Azure Devops) is a really broad question, you need to be more concrete with what have you tried and what doesnt work. I suggest starting a new question for that."